# Load Balancer with SSL Passthrough and server persistence

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, server, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I am looking for an SSL passthrough load balancer, i.e. I don't want the SSL connection to terminate at the load balancer. Instead, I want the data to pass through it encrypted to the appropriate server as decided by the load balancer's algorithm.

At the same time, I want that once my client program has established an SSL connection with a particular server, all the future connection attempts from that client are directed to that same server.

Digital Ocean [states here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-passthrough/) that Sticky sessions are not supported with SSL Passthrough load balancer, so it appears there is no way to store the data in the load balancer service itself.

Is there a service or any workaround that provides such an option?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Network Load Balancers [support sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) over TCP passthrough connections. They do this by sending all requests from the same IP address to the same target server. Of course that means that large groups of computers behind a NAT, like everyone in an office, are going to have their requests routed to the same target server, which could cause load imbalance.

AWS Application Load Balancers use cookies to manage sticky sessions, which avoids the NAT issue, but requires that the load balancer is able to decrypt the traffic in order to read the cookie.